# Replacing GET request with HEAD

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, get

I'm currently using cURL to send GET requests. However, I do not need the returned value, as the requests are more of commands, to let my server know to execute a php file or change settings and such. In this case, would it be more economical to use HEAD instead of GET? I have no need for the returned document at all. My second concern is if my server will interpret HEAD the same as GET, and will execute the functions.

So instead of:

```
GET /receiver.php?command=update_homepage
```

I want to use:

```
HEAD /receiver.php?command=update_homepage
```

Comment: What if it fails for whatever reason? Don't you want to get the response so you know about that

Comment: That's what HTTP response codes are for.

Comment: @d11wtq: Agreed an error code will tell you that a request has failed (and maybe allow for some vague terms regarding the reasons why), but to allow for greater information to be passed, GET would be a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure can use HEAD.  The server will invoke your PHP script as normal, with "HEAD" in `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]`.  Your script can act accordingly.

To send the request with cURL, set the option `CURLOPT_NOBODY` with `curl_setopt()`.